# How to deploy (sync) Rails 3.1 precompiled assets with Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

How can I deploy my precompiled assets of Rails 3.1 pipeline to s3?

I need a task to automate this syncing work with my assets bucket.

**EDIT:**

This gem is exactly which I need: https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync.

Comment: asset_sync is fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, that this shouldn't be a problem.
The filename is the result of the content of the given file.
And if you compile the files, upload them to S3 and update your environment.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"
```

I guess it should work.

Comment: This is a part of solution. But I want something like Capistrano task to push my changed precompiled assets to s3. I want to deploy, not a manually upload, any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You can fire

    rake assets:precompile

And then, this gem can help you to upload the compiled files to s3.
https://github.com/moocode/asset_id
Maybe you have to change one route...

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at the [jammit-s3](https://github.com/railsjedi/jammit-s3) project, for a good start at getting your compiled assets up to Amazon S3. I've been using it on a Rails 3 project that uses [jammit](https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit) for asset management. I was planning to take a crack at tweaking jammit-s3 to work with the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline. I stumbled onto your question while checking to see if anyone had else had already done so. Now that Rails 3.1 has been officially released, I'm confident that a good solution will be developed.

Comment: Seems to be a good option. I'm currently using manual upload with s3tools and still waiting for a better resource.